# Limiting subquery result based on main query value

Tags: mysql

I have a small table called 'prize' with 3 fields,

```
Event_id  | Place | Money
-------------------------
101       | 1     | 120
101       | 2     | 60
```

...etc.

Now the basic query with subquery is as follows:

```
Select Event_id,
    (SELECT money FROM prize WHERE place=1) AS 'First',
```

...etc.

The subquery obviously returns too many rows (as there are several events). How can I limit it to just returning the value that corresponds to the Event_id field?

I have tried many,many iterations without success, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more clear about the question.

Comment: select Event_id, Money from prize where eventId in (select eventId from prize where Place = 1) -- in case you are looking for subquery?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:-

```
Select Event_id,
(SELECT MAX(money) FROM prize WHERE place=1 LIMIT 1) AS 'First',
```

Comment: I tried that, but then it only returns 1 value for all the first place prizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the event in the sub query:-

```
SELECT Event_id,
    (SELECT money FROM prize AS sub1 WHERE sub1.Event_id = prize.Event_id AND place=1) AS 'First',
    .....
FROM prize
```

However if events have multiple rows, one for each place then this will return multiple rows. Could use DISTINCT to solve this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Event_id,
    (SELECT money FROM prize AS sub1 WHERE sub1.Event_id = prize.Event_id AND place=1) AS 'First',
    .....
FROM prize
```

However this is not likely to be efficient. It will perform the sub queries each once for each row on the prize table.

A possible solution would be to use an aggregate function to get a particular value depending on the value of place:-

```
SELECT Event_id,
    MAX(IF(place=1, money, 0)) AS 'First',
    MAX(IF(place=2, money, 0)) AS 'Second',
    ......
FROM prize
GROUP BY Event_id
```